# Dispaly all the data from a mysql table with additional information from second table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have two tables in mysql db.Table_1 and Table_2 I am displaying the whole table in HTML using the following code :

```
<table>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "database";
$results = null;
try {
     $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
     $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Table_1"); 
     $stmt->execute();
     $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
     $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
     echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
?> 
<table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <?php foreach($results as $key=>$row) { ?>
        <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row['Name'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['Address'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['Email'];?></td>
    </tr>
     <?php } ?>
       </tbody>
</table>
</table>
```

Now i want to add one more column to this HTML table where the data will be coming from Table_2.In this Table_2 there will be multiple comments inserted for a single post in Table_1.

Iam querying the latest comment for the post using the query statement :

```
SELECT comment FROM Table_2 WHERE id = (SELECT id 
FROM Table_2 WHERE post_id = 10 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Here we are specifying the post_id = 10 but when iam usiong SELECT * FROM Table_1" to display all the data from table_1 how should i specify to display a latest comment for that particular post in table_2

Table-1 Structure:

```
+-------+---------+---------+---------+
|  id   |  Name   | Address | Email   |
+-------+---------+---------+---------+
|   1   |   ABC   |   ABC   |   ABC   |
|   2   |   DEF   |   DEF   |   DEF   |
+-------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Table-2 Structure:

```
+-------+-------------+---------+
|  id   |  Table_1_id | Comments|
+-------+-------------+---------+
|   1   |     1       |   X     | 
|   2   |     1       |   Y     | 
|   3   |     2       |   Z     | 
+-------+-------------+---------+
```

HTML to be displayed:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  Name   | Address | Email   | Comments|
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   ABC   |   ABC   |   ABC   |    Y    |
|   DEF   |   DEF   |   DEF   |    Z    | 
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show what have you tried, and go through joins before asking question

Comment: Do you need to see a counter of comments or only the latest comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all the posts along with its latest comment then you can use the  following query  :

```
SELECT 
Name,
Address,
Email,
finalTable.comment
FROM 
Table_1
INNER JOIN 
(

        SELECT 
        comment,
        Table_1_id
        FROM Table_2
        INNER JOIN 
        (   SELECT 
             MAX(id) latest_comment_id
            FROM Table_2
            GROUP BY Table_1_id ) latestComments
        ON Table_2.id = latestComments.latest_comment_id
) finalTable
ON finalTable.Table_1_id = Table_1.id;
```

It will give an output result like below:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  Name   | Address | Email   | Comments|
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   ABC   |   ABC   |   ABC   |    Y    |
|   DEF   |   DEF   |   DEF   |    Z    | 
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

**Note:** If you want all the posts i mean those posts too which don't have any comment yet then replace the `INNER JOIN` by `LEFT JOIN`

[Demo Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a3378/2/0)

Comment: (

        SELECT 
        comment,
        Table_1_id
        FROM Table_2
        INNER JOIN 
        (   SELECT 
             MAX(id)



error near INNER JOIN(syntax error)

Comment: would you please post your `create table code`? the query is okay. may be a syntax issue @user5358888

Comment: found the syntax error. Corrected the query. Please check now @user5358888

Comment: what is finaltable.comment ?

Comment: that's the latest comment of the corresponding post. And finalTable is a temporary table created in the query. Please check the demo in my answer. @user5358888

Answer (score 0):

you can use [joins](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/pdo-mysql-join/5133) as below

```
 select Table_1.*
    from Table_1
    left join Table_2  on 
    (Table_1.id=Table_2.Table_1_id)
    and 
    Table_2.id>
    (select id from Table_2  
        where Table_1_id='10'
        order by id DESC LIMIT 2,1)
```

Comment: Why is Table_1.id = 10 ?

Comment: Tabl_1.id ='10' means the post having id 10.

Comment: Then i can only display one post in the html table..but i want to display all the posts

Comment: @user5358888 check the updated answer . Hope it help .

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [MySql JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) to retrieve data from multiple tables with the same query.
I see that you are using php [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php), you can use join like this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare(" SELECT Table1.*, Table_2.Comment FROM Table_2 
    LEFT JOIN Table_1 ON ( Table_2.Table_1_id=Table_1.id)
    WHERE id = (SELECT id 
    FROM Table_2 WHERE post_id = 10 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)");

if ($stmt->execute(array($getVars['Comment']))) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        print_r($row);
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont want to mention the post_id...as i want to display all the data in table_1 withe latest comment in table_2

Comment: You can use the code in my answer to do this. I've printed all, you need to edit the code in the while cycle adding your html table and choose what you want to display.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object